# How do I disable pathname expansion in bash?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

Suppose I'm a lazy bum and want to avoid putting every string in quotes when passing arguments to a function, how do I avoid the characters `*` and `?` being used by bash for patname expansion?

Simplified example:

```
fn () {
    echo "$1"
}
# shopt -s option - disable * and ?
fn not/*/expanded
fn neither\ should\ this/be/expanded?
fn 'accepted too*'
# shopt -u option - enable * and ?
```

This should output:

```
not/*/expanded
neither should this/be/expanded?
accepted too*
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option you arer looking for is `noglob` and should be set using the shell built-in `set`.

To enable it:

```
set -o noglob
```

To disable it:

```
set +o noglob
```

Or also with `set -f` and `set +f`.

Yet another method:

```
shopt -os noglob
```

and

```
shopt -ou noglob
```

Comment: It's not a `shopt` (shell option) but just an "option". Thanks for putting me on the right track.